# Grep exact match no dash

Tags: bash, grep

I have a list of genes like this one saved on a variable:

```
NOL6
NPPC
NPRL2
NRG1
NT5C1B
NUDT19
OSER1
PAEP
PARD3
PCDHA4
```

I want to grep all these genes at another list:

```
chr3 NPRL2
chr5 NT5C1B
chr5 NT5C1B-RDH14
chr2 NUDT19
chr21 ABC
```

I tried this:

```
grep -w "^$genes$" list.txt
```

The problem is that it returns to me genes with a dash too:

```
    chr3 NPRL2
    chr5 NT5C1B
    chr5 NT5C1B-RDH14
    chr2 NUDT19
```

I tried to use `-x` but it doesn't work as the complete line doesn't match because of the first column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to "anchor" the search patterns at the end of the lines and so:

```
NOL6$
NPPC$
NPRL2$
```

etc....

If you cannot amend the original file with the list of patterns, you can use sed and so with the patterns in file1 and the file to search as file:

```
grep -v -f <(sed 's/$/$/' file1) file
```

With sed, we are replacing the end of the line with $